# Assembly: How to know when local variables are being declared?

Tags: assembly

I'm looking at a study guide with the following question and answer:

```
Q. Write the corresponding C code
int decode2(int x, int y, int z)
1: movl 16(%ebp), %eax
2: movl 12(%ebp), %edx
3: subl %eax, %edx
4: movl %edx, %eax
5: imull 8(%ebp), %edx
6: sall $31, %eax
7: sarl $31, %eax
8: xorl %edx, %eax

Answer:
int decode2(int x, int y, int z) {
int t1 = y - z;
int t2 = x * t1;
int t3 = (t1 << 31) >> 31;
int t4 = t3 ˆ t2;
return t4;
}
```

I would have never guessed that exactly 4 local variables where created by looking at the assembly code. Is there some obvious way to tell that I'm not noticing?
A related question: How can you know which variable is being returned? In this case it's t4.

Edit: found out the answer to my secondary question - %eax is used for return values.

Comment: Flew past me as well. I think the answer to your question is: "No, there is no obvious way"

Comment: Surely this is wrong; `int t3 = t1 << 31; int t4 = t3 >> 31; int t5 = t4 ^ t2;` is obviously the right answer... OTOH, when noticing the lifetimes of the variables or register dependency chain (just counting the registers), one could figure out that there are only two local variables, `a` and `d`.